# Multiselection using jquery and fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
           
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                selectable: true,
                firstDay : 1,
                editable : true,

 
                select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {  
                    // Seçilen başlangıç ve bitiş tarihlerini al
                    var startDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    var endDate = end.subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
                    var selectedDays = [];

                    var currentDate = start;
                    while(currentDate <= end){
                        selectedDays.push(currentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                        currentDate.add(1, 'day')
                    }

                    if (startDate === endDate) {
                        $('#addEventModal').modal('show');
                        $('#addEventForm input[name="days"]').val(startDate); 
                    } else {
                       
                        $('#addEventModal').modal('show');
                        $('#addEventForm input[name="days"]').val(selectedDays.join(', '));
                    }    
                },

                height : 600,
                defaultView : 'month',
                events: '/manager/get_events', 

                });
               
            });

            $('#addEventModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
                var selectedDays = $('#addEventForm input[name="days"]').val().split(', ');
                var eventsExist = false;

 
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedDays.length; i++) {
                    var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                        return event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') === selectedDays[i];
                    });

                    if (events.length > 0) {
                        eventsExist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (eventsExist) {
                    $('#deleteEventsBtn').show();
                } else {
                    $('#deleteEventsBtn').hide();
                }
            });
           
            $('#deleteEventsBtn').click(function(){
                var selectedDays = $('#addEventForm input[name = "days"]').val().split(', ')
                    deleteEventsByDay(selectedDays);
                            });

 
            function deleteEventsByDay(selectedDays) {
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedDays.length; i++) {
                    var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                        return event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') === selectedDays[i];
                    });

 
                    for (var j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
                        deleteEvent(events[j].id);
                    }
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event) {
                        return event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') === selectedDays[i];

                    });
                }
            }
```

```html
<div id="addEventModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title text-primary" style="align-content: center;">Add Event</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="addEventForm" action="{{url_for('Manager_crud_hours.add_bulk_events')}}" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="project_id">Project:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></span>
                                <select class="form-control" id="project_id" name="project_id">
                                                        {% for row in projects %}
                                <option value="{{row.project_id}}">{{row.project_name}}</option>
                                                        {%endfor%}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Worked Hours:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="time" placeholder="Enter Worked Hours">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Worked Day:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="days" id="addEventDay"  placeholder="Select Worked Day"  readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class = "modal-footer">
                            <button class="btns btns-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                            <button class="btns btns-danger" id="deleteEventsBtn" style = "display: none;">Delete</button>

 
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have a calendar that I use fullcalendar.i.o. Using this calendar, I save some transactions to the database with the help of mysql and flask. But the part that I can't do now is not related to mysql and flask. The problem is, when I do a bulk selection I want a modal to pop up. When I do this on days without events on the calendar, there should only be an add button on the modal. If there is an event on the selected days, the delete button should come next to the add button and mass deletion should be done in this way. The error I get is this, when I make a batch selection, delete does not come even if the day is full or idle, but when I close the modal and try again without refreshing the page, this time everything works correctly. I can't find the reason for this.